# Using node js in android studio

Tags: android, node.js, android-studio, speech-recognition

I found this project on GitHub - [Package to use the ginger api : English grammar checker](https://github.com/abcfantasia/nodejs-ginger)

I want to use this in my android application where I have used Google speech recognition.

Can I get any guidelines about how can I incorporate this in my android project.

Comment: Read [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/). Build your Android project with something like `Cordova`.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that.

Comment: Can you please tell me, how can I make use of above package in cordova in an app

Comment: @first, stackoverflow is not a replacement for google search or college classes. You need to go through "Get started" or similar articles of software you want to use. Also, please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) articles first. Then, do your homework researching what's available on the internet and try to craft something yourself. And only after all this is done, if you're stuck with some particular error - you're welcome to ask about that particular error here.

Comment: I do research every time.But from next time I will share that with question.Thank you for your suggestion.I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check spell error in android app using google speech recogniser.you will do it using 
[SpellCheckerService.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/spell-checker-framework).

Comment: Can I check grammatical errors through spell checker?

Comment: No you can't check grammatically errors using spellchecker . read this :- http://www.afterthedeadline.com/api.slp

Comment: I have checked that already.But how to use that in my project.I am clueless about it.Can you tell me how to do it

Comment: First you get data from speech recogniser and store in string variable then you pass this string data in checkDocument api. you get a typical html response .